# CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I saw this error sometime ago in our AWS installation.

`CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection.`

We resolved it by doing some lambda changes. However, I am trying to see if these logs are stored anywhere so that we can set some alerts on that. Can anyone please guide me where I can possibly see these logs?

Comment: CloudFront has [access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html). But I don't know if this particular error would be there.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for the response. I checked the Cloudfront logs, but did not see this or anything related to this.